# Why do residents keep digging holes on the beach?

Tags: tomodachi-life

Every once in a while, one of the island residents is on the beach, digging a hole.  I stayed at the beach and watched for a few minutes before getting bored and deciding to check on other Miis.

Do Miis ever find anything while digging?  Do I have to keep watching in order to get that item?